# MVC trying to do a Get request

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do a GET request on MVC 4.0 (WebServiceREST) that some method use POST and other use GET but I cant make it works

I used `[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` but It didnt work still getting `"The requested resource does not support the HTTP 'GET' method"`

My Controller:

```
  public class RecuperarDatosAppController : ApiController
{


    #region RecuperarClasesColectivas
    [System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<ActividadesColectivas>))]
    public IHttpActionResult RecuperarClasesColectivas(short idInstalacion, string secretKey = "NOSECRETKEY")
    {
        BsSecurity bSecurity = new BsSecurity(BsSecurity.Tipo.Publica);
        if (bSecurity.comprobar(secretKey))
        {
            BsActividadesColectivas bsActividades = new BsActividadesColectivas();

            return Ok(bsActividades.GetActividadesColectivas(idInstalacion));
        }
        return NotFound();
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to prepend "Get" to methods that you wish to expose by by GET requests.

So try `GetRecuperarClasesColectivas` instead of `RecuperarClasesColectivas`.

You'll still call it by `/api/RecuperarClasesColectivas/id` for example, the routing just needs the "Get" part adding.

Answer (score 2):

Though you state this is MVC and tagged it as such, it's actually Web API, because you're inheriting from [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx). So you should decorate the method with the `[HttpGet]` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpgetattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) from the `System.Web.Http` namespace. Note that renaming it to have `Get` prepended like Yoink is suggesting isn't necessary, although that is the common convention.

Comment: Oh I missed the difference in namespace.

Comment: If i just add "Get" like Yoink suggest and It works, if I eliminated the "Get" it doesnt work, could you give me a example code?  i tryied `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]` but it doesnt work

Comment: @D4rWiNS That's because it's the `System.Web.Http` namespace, so just use `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]` (Mvc -> Http). You can just use the shorthand of `[HttpGet]` since you will be using `System.Web.Http` for returning your results as well as other things. If you require the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace for something else then you'll have to just use `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]`.